# setMonth in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am looking for a way to programmatically set the showing month of the jquery ui. Something like setDate but for month.

```
$el = $(body);
$el.datepicker()
$el.datepicker('setDate', '2015-01-31')
$el.datepicker('setMonth, '2015-03') // wanted feature
```

So change the visible month without changing the selected date, is there such a feature that I have missed or is there another way to get the same result.

Comment: Okay, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: setMonth does not exist (to my knowledge) so I am looking for another way to get the same result

Answer (score 1):

You could read the current date first & store the day value. After that call `setDate` with your custom date object:

```
function setMonth(year, month) {
    var currentDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate") || new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDay();
    newDate = new Date(year, month, day);
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", newDate);
}
```

You could extend the datepicker widget using [widget factory](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/) if you'd like to call `setMonth()` method directly on a datepicker object.

JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/hopivuzeye/1/

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this using a bit of a hack (works on Firefox 47).

```
var DateObject = new Date('2015-01-31'); // the month of this date will be selected
$("#date").datepicker();
$("#date").on('focus', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
        $(this).datepicker("setDate", DateObject);
        $(this).val('')
    }
});
```